# Testing on categorical variables Using sk-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm trying to generate and test model a on categorical variables using sci-kit learn. I'm interested in using the `one-hot encoder` function to encode these categorical variables in a sklearn pipeline after imputation of the data and before a random forest.

```
estimator = Pipeline([
                    ("imputer", Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy="median",axis=0)),
                    ("dummy", OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=np.where(mask), handle_unknown = 'ignore')),
                  ("forest", RF())])
```

Training works fine, but the trouble comes when I try to test a generated model on new data. The categorical variables possible for this problem are not bounded, and not all possible categorical variables show up in the training dataset. So there might be test data that contain categorical variables that the model has never seen before, resulting in  crashes in the prediction process due to mismatched dimensions.

As a concrete example, say one of the features I'm training on is `fruit_name`. The model trains on many examples of various fruits, including bananas, apples, and oranges. `fruit_name` is one-hot encoded in the pipeline. However, say I have test data that contains a `fruit_name` that the model has never seen before, like kiwi. Then the test data will have an extra column to the training data. Alternatively, say the test data doesn't actually contain bananas,apples or oranges. Then it will have fewer columns to the training data. Either way, model testing will crash.

How do I handle this issue with categorical variables using the sklearn pipeline?

Comment: IMHO, this is a theoretic problem. I mean, if you are aiming for **supervised learning** you should ask first: "what's the sense of testing on something that the algorithm has never seen?" Maybe you should shift the strategy to some sort of unsupervised learning, some clustering for example where train and test does not make sense. But this is only a possible suggestion, marked the question to follow up on new answers :)